# Golang multiple json

Tags: json, go

I have a json that I send in response to the client, it is available in 2 variants, all the difference will be in one field name push/pull, how can I do this without duplicating the structure for the sake of one tag

```
 "message": "Project updated successfully.",
        "data": {
            "push": {
                "projects": [
                    {
                        "name": "test",
                        "summary": "nn",
                    
                    }
                ],
                "events": []
            }
        }
    }
    "message": "Project updated successfully.",
        "data": {
            "pull": {
                "projects": [
                    {
                        "name": "test",
                        "summary": "nn",
                    
                    }
                ],
                "events": []
            }
        }
    }
```

`

I was thinking about making the date field interfaces and substituting different structures

Comment: *"how can I do this without duplicating the structure"* -- Use a _named_ struct type.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simply define a single type with both Push and Pull fields:

```golang
type A struct {
    Message string `json:"message"`
    Data    struct {
        Push *B `json:"push,omitempty"`
        Pull *B `json:"pull,omitempty"`
    } `json:"data"`
}

type B struct {
    Projects []struct {
        Name    string `json:"name"`
        Summary string `json:"summary"`
    } `json:"projects"`
    Events []interface{} `json:"events"`
}
```

After decoding check for nil to figure out which kind of events are represented.